# Is it possible to combine present perfect and past simple in this sentence

Tags: past-tense

> 1. Even if you have told us before we have been surprised because it has only been raining a little
> 2. Even if you have told us before we were surprised because it has only been raining a little

What is the best sentence because I am wondering if the second one is correct. *We were surprised* refers to one single moment and *has only been raining* to a duration

Comment: Could you expand a little on the context in which either of these sentences might be uttered? What is the speaker saying exactly? At any rate, the first one places the emphasis on the present, while the second one places it on that action in the past, as though you're remembering it. So I guess the question really boils down to what you want the sentence to say.

Comment: I am on holidays on Ireland I ve been there for 7 days and am very surprised because the weather is hot and shiny,I am not remembering this feeling so I guess the first one is better

Comment: Even if you **have told us** before we **are surprised** because it has only been raining a little. is normal here.

Comment: @YvesLefol what is it that they did (or didn't?) tell you before? And what are you surprised by?

Answer (score 0):

I don't find either version particularly idiomatic. Sometimes there's no way to avoid using Perfect forms - but example #1 has *three* unnecessary instances.

Example #2 is in some ways even worse, because it introduces a *Simple **Past*** form *(we **were** surprised)* into a ***Present*** Perfect context *(you **have told** us, it **has been** raining)*.

Finally, I don't think this is a suitable context for using ***even if*** instead of ***although***. As a general principle, we only use the construction ***even if*** [Assertion 1], [Assertion 2] in contexts where *[Assertion 1]* is a *possibility* (which for the sake of argument the speaker is willing to concede *might* be true). In OP's example it simply doesn't make sense that the speaker might be referring to the *possibility* that he might have been forewarned - the whole point of the entire utterance is based on ***the fact that he had been forewarned***.

Therefore I suggest that to fix the "basic syntax" we'd need something like ...

> *Even though you told us before, we were surprised because it has only rained a little*.

But to be honest, even though I'm not sure *exactly* what OP's utterance is supposed to mean, I don't think it's something a native speaker would ever say. Taking a wild guess at the intended meaning, perhaps...

> *Although you warned us [to expect dry weather], we were surprised how little rain there was*.

(In any context I can reasonably imagine, the speaker would probably place exaggerated heavy stress on one or more of the words ***were, surprised, how, little, rain***.)

Comment: first, I must tell you that we are exchanging house with an Irish family. 

 Before leaving for Ireland I had exchanged many emails  and in each email received they said the weather was very hot.

It  has been a surprise because the surprise of the  good weather began when we arrived and still continues up to now 

Has been raining  only a little because it is still going on

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand exactly what your example is trying to say. If they told you it was (and by implication, *would continue to be*) hot, and this turned out to be true, why would you be surprised?

Comment: I chose this tense present perfect  to emphasise my surprise, it was not a single event but the surprise has been repeated everyday since I have been in ireland(7 days)

Comment: It would be much easier for readers if you repeated the sentences so we don't have to do the work of going up and down from the question.

Comment: Even though you told us before we arrived *about the weather*, we have been surprised by how good it is and that it has only been raining a little. It works fine.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I'm not sure exactly how to generalize the syntactic principle involved (I never heard of a "Royal Order of Adverbs"). But when there are two consecutive adverbial clauses both referring back to ***you told us*** like that, I find it very "non-idiomatic" to specify the ***time of being told*** *(before we arrived)* before the ***subject matter*** *(about the weather)*. If one of the two adverbial elements is much longer than the other, we usually give the shorter one first. That doesn't apply here (both are just three words), but I still have a very strong pregference

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have told us before we have been surprised because it has only been raining a little.

Rewrite, based on the explanation about the trip to Ireland:

- Even though **you told us before we arrived** about the weather, we **have been surprised** by how good it is and that it **has only been raining** a little.
- Even though **you told us before we arrived** about the weather, we **are still surprised** by how good it is and that it **has only been raining** [or has only rained] a little. [fixed]

Two verbs in the present perfect that apply to what you are continuing to experience in the present after being informed at a specific moment in the past about the weather. The surprise can be expressed two ways.